# How to ignore only scroll events on widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm displaying iframes in `Html` widgets, in the `ListView.builder`.

I can't scroll the page because of the iframes. I can only scroll when I start dragging from an empty space between them.

I tried to wrap `Html` widget with `AbsorbPointer` and `IgnorePointer`, they are working, and I can scroll, but I don't want to completely disable the pointer-events on iframes. Because some of them are clickable(e.g it has a tabbar for example: bitcoin | etherium on first graph)

[image]

Question is, can I absorb all the drag and scroll events for these iframes, let the user scroll the page normally, but also let them click on iFrames?

```
class HubContentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HubContentWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.hub,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final HubCategory hub;

  @override
  State<HubContentWidget> createState() => _HubContentWidgetState();
}

class _HubContentWidgetState extends State<HubContentWidget> {
  late Future<List<HubItem>> _hubFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _hubFuture = Service.getHubItems(uri: widget.hub.uri);
    super.initState();
  }

  bool absorbPointers = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<HubItem>>(
      future: _hubFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final items = snapshot.data!;
          if (items.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('No items found'));
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              /// This widget takes all the pointer events 
              /// and prevents scrolling.
              return Html(
                data: items[index].content.formatted,
                navigationDelegateForIframe: (request) {
                  return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                },
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Html widget from `flutter_html-2.2.1`

iframe example

```
<p><iframe title="The rise and fall of cryptocurrency" aria-label="Interactive line chart" id="datawrapper-chart-acQ2e" src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/acQ2e/4/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 0; min-width: 100% !important; border: none;" height="450"></iframe><script type="text/javascript">!function(){"use strict";window.addEventListener("message",(function(e){if(void 0!==e.data["datawrapper-height"]){var t=document.querySelectorAll("iframe");for(var a in e.data["datawrapper-height"])for(var r=0;r<t.length;r++){if(t[r].contentWindow===e.source)t[r].style.height=e.data["datawrapper-height"][a]+"px"}}}))}();
</script></p>
```

Comment: please attach your code and what you have achieved

Comment: @mohammadesmailiadded code added.

Comment: please add an example of data you passed to `Html` too, thanks

Comment: I tried your code for single listview and it didnt scroll horizontally, and in listviewB i could scroll vertically without empty spaces, did i miss something? or does this example iframe scroll horizontally?

Comment: @mohammadesmaili thanks for checking out. I don't need horizontal scrolling and there's no code to scroll horizontally. Problem is, when I want to vertically scroll the page, whenever I tap on the iframes, iframe takes all the touch events and wouldn't let me scroll. I need to find an empty area that is not occupied by iframes to tap and scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Well i think this way let you scroll, hope this works for you too,

I set `scrollDirection` of builder to `Axis.vertical` and wrap the Html with `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 10,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Html(
              data:
                  """<p><iframe title="The rise and fall of cryptocurrency" aria-label="Interactive line chart" id="datawrapper-chart-acQ2e" src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/acQ2e/4/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 0; min-width: 100% !important; border: none;" height="450"></iframe><script type="text/javascript">!function(){"use strict";window.addEventListener("message",(function(e){if(void 0!==e.data["datawrapper-height"]){var t=document.querySelectorAll("iframe");for(var a in e.data["datawrapper-height"])for(var r=0;r<t.length;r++){if(t[r].contentWindow===e.source)t[r].style.height=e.data["datawrapper-height"][a]+"px"}}}))}();
            </script></p>""",
              navigationDelegateForIframe: (request) {
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

this result is by your iframe example and worked well for me, the result be like:

[image: result]

look in this result i scroll with tapping on iframe, try it and let me know the result

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that's working? Or can you explain? I've tested, and nothing changed. As for the code, Axis.vertical is default for ListView.builder anyway. And horizontal but never scrollable SingleChildScrollView also wasn't helpful.

Comment: I took screen record look i tap on iframe and move

Comment: Can you tell me which android, flutter, and flutter_html version you're using? And are you sure you had the same bug and fix with the following? Maybe your version didn't have the same issue.

Comment: `flutter_html: ^2.2.1` and `Flutter 3.3.0`, and i test on real device `samsung a40`, maybe your flutter version is old or my device support it, IDK , i didnt have your bug even before i test it and it was fine, i add this solution maybe change your output

Comment: Yes, it's an old project with early Flutter 2.  I'll check if it's from Flutter or a real device. Thanks for the input. That was helpful. On the other hand, changes in the code seem redundant and not helpful.

Comment: Oh thats it, so flutter 3 solves your problem and just need to migrate, i just wonder if this helps and send here to help you ,when i tried your code it was ok before, im glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that answer from @mohammad esmaili should be helpful for your case. But if you still has the issue because using old flutter or sdk and not planning to migrate.

You can add logic(boolean) to turn on/off AbsorbPointer.
some example UX scenario:

- Add a button or switch that can enable/disable the AbsorbPointer each iframe
- Add a logic at the container/iframe when user click the area 1 time, it will turn/off the absorbPointer

Answer (score -1):

You can use ListView.builder physics attribute with NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), if you want
you can also bind it to a variable that can be determined with a one-line if, for example; isDraggable==true? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(): AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics

Comment: I think there's no use case that I want to have NeverScrollableScrollPhysics().

Problem is, Html widgets are absorbing taps in ListView.builder. I can only scroll from empty spaces, where pointer event go to list without blocked: like between two Html widgets. 

I can make ListView.builder to take pointer events again by wrapping child widgets(Html) with AbsorbPointer or IgnorePointer. But this solution then makes iframes non-interactive.